# Pass Two api In onClick react mui popup

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, material-ui

Here the functionality are working properly and add a next button to my popup and next button functionality is close current popup and open next popup code is

```
function StackOverflow() {
  // We create a state dep that holds all our modals open/close state
  const [myModals, setMyModals] = useState({
    modalA: true,
    modalB: false,
  })

  // This will return an api in which we can toggle, close or open a modal
  // ie: set the boolean to true or false 
  const getModalHanlder = (modalName) => {
    return {
      isOpen: myModals[modalName],
      open: () => setMyModals((state) => ({ ...state, [modalName]: true })),
      close: () => setMyModals((state) => ({ ...state, [modalName]: false })),
      toggle: () =>
        setMyModals((state) => ({ ...state, modalA: !state[modalName] })),
    }
  }

  const modalA = getModalHanlder("modalA")
  // Here we invoke our function and pass on the desired modal prop name from 
  // which we desire to create an api 
  

  // We can then create this for another modal, modalB
  const modalB = getModalHanlder("modalB")
  return (
    <div>
      <b>MODAL_A: {`${modalA.isOpen}`}</b>
      <br />
      <button onClick={modalA.toggle}>TOGGLE</button>
      <button onClick={modalA.close}>CLOSE</button>
      <button onClick={modalA.open}>OPEN</button>
      <button onClick={modalA.close;modalB.open}>Next</button> // error is here
    </div>
  )
}
```

the **modalB** is open but the modalA not close the vscode show `JSX expressions may not use the comma operator. Did you mean to write an array?ts(18007)` this error, pass two api in onclick event. how to solve this issue, i am new in react

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't assign two functions at once. Wrap them with an anon function.

```
<button onClick={() => {
    modalA.close();
    modalB.open()
}}>Next</button>
```